# Was I too conservative in asking my team to test a production database mass-update script?

Tags: software-industry

Before you say this is a no-brainer, I should qualify that the script is VERY simple.  I agree with the developer who wrote the script that the probability of something going wrong was somewhat remote.

Essentially, the script relabeled a set of historical records (about a half million of them) temporarily to alleviate a critical performance problem for one of our clients.  This happened around 4:30pm on a Friday and I think everybody was tired and wanted to sign off for the week.

Our production environment is probably medium to small sized.  It hosts hundreds of tenants, averaging a dozen users each, and receives somewhere between 6 and 30 transactions a second.  However, we are SOC compliant and need to maintain those credentials to keep some of our larger clients.

I'll also say that I came in to the conversation somewhat heavy handed - I said that "We would" test this script, that there was no question, but I met with such anger from one developer that I decided to roll back that decision and asked the team to vote on it.

The team voted 3 to 2 to test and because I've worked with these people for years, I'm pretty sure they didn't feel compelled to do so.  I could always be wrong of course.

I've had VERY BAD experiences in the past with production mass update scripts, and so I'm worried my past caused me to be too conservative.

As the director of the group, I'm always concerned that pushing decisions through with my authority (instead of reasoned arguments) could shut down lines of communication, but this felt like an obvious case to me where testing was required, and I didn't understand why I would need to explain.

After testing for an hour with no problems, we were able to run the production update successfully.  The developer who was opposed to testing made several comments during this hour that this work was unnecessary and that there was no chance of anything going wrong.  After we finished, the same developer commented that we could have been "in the same place an hour ago."

Was I out of line and too conservative to require the hour of testing?

Comment: Why did 6 people have to do the testing? A post mortem on this is not "was I wrong to insist on a test?" or "why is one of my staff so misaligned with both me and the rest of the team?" but "why did this test take so long?"

Comment: @KateGregory Sorry that I excluded important information.  I can answer the question portion of the comment if that helps.  This was a critical performance fix and needed to go into production as soon as reasonably possible.  2 people were testing.  2 developers and myself were available to supply the script, any data needed for decision making and to generally facilitate by performing updates to test environments, etc.  I hope that helps.

Comment: "there was no chance of anything going wrong." - I can only assume this developer is a rookie. Anybody with more than 5 mins experience in software development knows this is laughably false.

Comment: It's impossible for us to answer the question posed and off-topic. Being a good directior involves weighing up a whole bunch of factors, and not deferring to a vote, or asking internet strangers.

Comment: _"[..] there was no chance of anything going wrong"_ I have regularly said this (and still do), only to have it sometimes blow up in my face. If you want to take a chance, it can be acceptable, but you do need to know how to recover if it does blow up in your face.

Comment: @LaconicDroid Indeed, and a manager should never leave someone with that level of overconfidence near a production database on a Friday afternoon unsupervised! Would love to know if they are pushing db scripts out via some controlled procedure that verifies everything and keeps an audit trail, hence the time lag, or they just let devs fire up SSMS/pgadmin/SqlDeveloper/whatever...

Comment: @LaconicDroid Wrong. I have seen a senior dev with over 20 years of experience and overseeing a small team not just stepping on the rake every now and then, but basically walking over them nonstop. Basically a week or so each and every month was spent on something blowing up in their face and the team dealing with the fallout because "obviously, nothing could possibly go wrong". Some people just never learn.

Comment: “Imagine this is a nuclear power plant with a bad history. Can any of you image _any_ series of events that would cause this to fail?”

Comment: Also the mumbling developer should be lectured on being a team player and respect the team decisions. If he cannot do that the team needs one that can instead.

Comment: Actually, there is a Workplace issue here regarding how tasks are scheduled, tracked, and managed. Nothing should be allowed to be last-minute. I've added an answer to that effect.

Comment: @Lodinn - Sounds like your senior dev had one year of experience they repeated 20 times rather than 20 years of experience. Sadly, not all that unusual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will assume a few things here: you have been given the job of Director, not because of some random draw of your name from a hat or you being the nephew of the owner, but rather through the normal interview process and picking an experienced person for the job.

> I've had VERY BAD experiences in the past with production mass update scripts, and so I'm worried my past caused me to be too conservative.

Yes. But isn't that what you were hired for? Your *experiences*? Isn't that why they did hire you, and not a random person of the street?

If your experience says this needs to be tested, and you are the director, then *it needs to be tested*. Period.

While I agree on your assessment on whether it needs testing or not, that is not the point. Even if I disagreed. You were not hired to *ignore* you past experiences, you were hired *because* of them.

Comment: Agreed.  Thanks for bringing some clarity to the issue.

Comment: I will say that the test could have easily been put off until the next Monday because it wasn't important. 

If it was important then it shows poor planning on the person who decided that they needed to test it at 4:30 PM.

Comment: @Questor How do you "plan better" for a critical problem reported for example at 14:00 and fixed on dev at 16:30? I'm not sure what your job is, but where I work, "critical problems" don't get planned in advance or only conveniently happen at 09:30 on Tuesdays.

Comment: Good testing prevents critical problems. Having critical problems that appear out of nowhere means that you are bad at testing. Because you didn't discover them before deployment...

Comment: Indeed. Name a single company that is good enough at testing, that they *never* have critical errors? We are all just humans and so we will at all times have critical problems pop up. Good companies less, bad companies more. But it will never be zero.

Answer (score 15):

> Was I out of line and too conservative to require the hour of testing?

Without knowing the details, and the ramifications of a script failure, there's no way to know if you were too conservative or not.

But you are a Director? And you asked the team to vote on it? I don't understand the point of that.

You don't shed responsibility by holding a vote.

If you aren't technically able to make the decision by yourself, you should ask for opinions from those who are technically competent, then make the decision for yourself.

Either way, the buck stops with you, so if some of the team don't like it, that's just unfortunate.

Comment: @joi-strazzere Thanks you for your answer. Would it be fair to summarize your answer as, "You are the director, so if you are technically competent, you should have stuck with requiring the testing regardless of what anybody else thought?"

Comment: @DaveWelling You don't even need to be technically competent, you just need to understand the risk factors. You then make a judgement call.

Comment: *"You don't shed responsibility by holding a vote."* - I think the purpose of the vote was not to shed his own responsibilities, but to examine collective opinion (and, as the case may be, add weight to his own judgment). You have to be careful about acting like a dictator amongst other experts; you've either got to enjoy an enormous level of trust and deference (rarely the case), or you're quickly going to be picking up the pieces of a shattered staff function where all the better birds have flown.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, you might prefer it not to be a democracy, but in software teams, the opinion of those executing the work often has real clout, departures often lead to an awful sting for the productivity of the function left behind (but equal or higher pay for the leaver in a new role), and managers are often no more senior in age or technical skill than the staff they manage. Think of it like managing a group of surgeons - an administrative manager, even a competent surgeon, can't simply dictate medical judgments to others who themselves have strong expertise on medical matters.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, well it is to do with your preferences, because you are urging him towards a particular mentality and behavioural style. Little of what is real can be inferred from job titles, and clearly the overall tenor of his post suggests he works in an environment where he relies on maintaining collegiate relationships, and where a style of issuing arbitrary directions would not wash for long. To reiterate my original point, he is not shedding his responsibilities, he is performing them by ensuring that potential conflicts are managed effectively.

Answer (score 10):

> I've had VERY BAD experiences in the past with production mass update
> scripts, and so I'm worried my past caused me to be too conservative.

That seems to me like your work has too many systematic failures.

You were right to be conservative for something that's so revenue-critical

> I'll also say that I came in to the conversation somewhat heavy handed
>
> - I said that "We would" test this script, that there was no question, but I met with such anger from one developer that I decided to roll
>   back that decision and asked the team to vote on it.
>
> The team voted 3 to 2 to test and because I've worked with these
> people for years, I'm pretty sure they didn't feel compelled to do so.
> I could always be wrong of course.

Work is not a democracy. If the vote had gone the other way and if things had gone wrong, you would have been on the hook for the blame.

With that said, deploying such a script at 4:30PM on a Friday is asking for trouble. Everyone is likely to be in a rush and make mistakes. And if something does go wrong, that means someone is going to be stuck working on Friday night or during the weekend.

Ask yourself. Did that angry developer usually get off at 4:30PM or on 5PM on Fridays? Was someone waiting for him? And how would you like it if a boss waited until the last minute before you're just about to clock off before they asked you to do something really important?

Could this kind of script have been run earlier in the week? Or later? May be next Monday, you should run a post-mortem debriefing session. If this was really a surprise that such a script needed be run at the very last minute on a Friday, maybe you need to change your systems to give yourself more leeway the next time around.

> After we finished, the same developer commented that we could have
> been "in the same place an hour ago."

And yes, that's what work is. Sometimes, a lot of work is incredibly redundant. Surgeons, accountants, pilots, programmers, DBAs, etc. Most of the work professionals do is making sure they're not making mistakes.

Comment: *"you would have been on the hook for the blame"* - it seems quite reasonable to think that they would all have been on the hook for the cleanup to some degree. As you say, the real issue here might be the timing of the initial work and the failure to build in after-hours cover (by means other than sweating those already working 9-5).

Comment: @Steve, It doesn't matter if some of the underlings are on the hook for the blame. When a system is behaving poorly, management gets the blame. The buck stops with management.

Comment: If that were the case, then he'd only be on the hook if he was the *highest* manager. Really, different environments have different attitudes to blame. A manager of professional staff would not normally be blamed for misjudgment, if it ensued from acting in accordance with the majority opinion at the time the judgment was made. Even if they would be blamed, that could be incentive for keeping the team on your side, to provide a degree of protection and solidarity against unreasonable superiors - in contrast to your assumption that the manager would prefer to stand alone on their own judgment.

Comment: @Steve A workplace is not a democracy. If you make a bad call, it really doesn't matter how many people made the same call. The only thing that matters is if you should have known better.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, why would he have known better, if several other professionals didn't? That's the point you're not engaging with.

Comment: @Steve More or different experience. Or a different weighting to what is considered important. Or knowing more information about risk. What other people say may help inform what you should know, but in itself not security against making bad calls.

Comment: @Steve For instance, a director may know the history of a particular client, and know how much they would kick a fuss if they suffered a problem. An engineer may not know this. Or an engineer may it's incredibly dangerous, but the director knows the company is willing for the client to be a sacraficial lamb should push come to shove.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, indeed but some of that is more about commercial judgment, which didn't seem to be the nature of the OP's problem. For example, he didn't say "will the client tolerate mistakes if we make them? Let's vote...". The question was what risk the work posed (something that is a matter of expert technical judgment), and whether the testing would mitigate that risk enough to justify the time spent on the mitigation (also a matter of expert technical judgment). Both the quality of the work, and the actual quality of any testing of it, typically relies on the developer themselves.

Comment: @Steve We really don't know what the director SHOULD be accessing in this circumstance. It appears the director is using previous experiences of upgrade failures to inspire them to be more conservative, so it may be the case that the director engages with multiple teams, and this team does not have that history. My point is there are often a range of factors that the engineers may not be aware of, which is why typically the person making the decision is on the hook. If they were fed bad information, then whom gave them that info would be on the hook too. Wether it be an engineer, AE, QA, etc.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, there are certainly many things managers may know which engineers don't, but whether the code is likely to work, and to what degree a specific testing proposal will mitigate any risk of damage, is not something that could be expected to be within the private knowledge of the manager only. The engineers themselves must make those judgments as part of designing code that tends to work properly, and to ensure that tests are designed or executed in ways that are most likely to identify problems with the code, and their closest engagement with this makes them best placed to judge.

Comment: @Steve The engineers are probably best placed to understand the risk factors involved with some aspect of the change, but that is one input into the decision making process. If a director takes all the inputs, and makes a bad decision, they are on the hook. If an input to that decision making process was bad, wither it's the opinion of the engineers, company policy, technology stack, client communication, QA reporting, external unknowable factors, etc. that takes whatever portion of the blame is suitable.

Comment: @Steve The whole point of a retrospective analysis is to figure out where it went wrong. You can't just blame everybody involved and call it a day. Ultimately, if a director simply decides to shirk their responsibility to make executive decisions, and instead defer to a group of individuals, and take something akin to a vote, they are not doing their job.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, but the director was taking inputs, by putting the matter to the vote. If the director was wrong, then so were most of his professional staff, and that is relevant because it tends to suggest that the decision was reasonable at the time it was made, even if things later go wrong. If higher management are determined not to accept that reasonable decisions are sometimes commensurate with things going wrong, then that is all the more reason for having the majority opinion declared overtly in advance, to provide ballast against the behaviour of higher managers if things go wrong.

Comment: @Steve A vote is clearly not a sane way of coming to a conclusion. Each participant will have different levels of understanding of the issue, different skill sets, and different risk profiles. Should the opinion of a senior count for double? I am not doubting for one second that sometimes a good decision leads to bad outcomes. What I am suggesting is that 100% of engineers in a team can say something is safe, but it can still be the wrong decision because there are other considerations that should have been made that the engineers would not have known.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, but presumably he would not have chosen to put it to a vote if those "other" considerations that only he could know about were prevailing, given that he retains right to determine whether a question is resolved by vote. Moreover the OP didn't ask for advice on the sanity of voting (and the result did in fact accord with his prior individual judgment), but I note both you and several others seem to have taken exception to the very principle of it, as if no sensible manager would ever use that approach, and as if managers typically posses more (not less) detailed understanding.

Comment: @Steve I don't know why you'd make a presumption like that. Calling a vote to me is a clear sign that the decision making process is suspect.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, it may be that you have criteria for how good decisions are made, which doesn't accord well with how software development is successfully practiced to cope with its challenges (and to stay within sensible budgets). I've drawn the analogy with surgery and surgeons - I don't have the space to fully develop the analogy, but the crucial point is that the relationship between management and working surgeons is complicated by the non-routine nature of the task and the fact that it involves autonomous working in the theatre and a large number of complicated judgements... (1/3)

Comment: ...and (to exert control) the manager needs to influence the judgments the surgeon makes later, rather than simply substituting their own. The manager simply telling the surgeon to go into threate and cut, when the surgeon objects, would usually cause damage. Even if the objection is illegitimate or non-surgical, the subjective irritation and distraction caused to the surgeon by an unresolved grievance, would undermine performance where an acceptable rate of success depends on very full concentration and delicate judgments. (2/3)

Comment: Likewise, a developer ordered to test (i.e. to examine the system for error) but not convinced that it is necessary or appropriate to do so, is likely to work so ineffectually as to make the time spent a complete waste - besides potentially provoking vindictive motives if the objection is severe and the means to overcome it terroristic (which might be only implied, such as expecting to be fired for refusal), the developer is at least likely to feel an absence of intrinsic motivation that drives the necessary full concentration on the work, and may be distracted by the conflict itself. (3/3)

Comment: @Steve With your surgeon example, there may be hospital policies that overrule the opinion of the surgeon, as may law, as may the patient wishes. Which is why hospital administrators are certainly a thing. Being a professional (and an adult) may mean that sometimes you have to do things you don't agree with.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, hospital administrators certainly are a thing, but my point is that to be effective they will behave similar to the manner of the OP. Nobody would seriously suggest that a sole hospital administrator (with no accountability to any medic they oversee) could be expected in general to have better medical judgement than a majority of several surgeons contemplating the same question, and (quite separately from who is right) scarce anyone would want their surgery done by a surgeon who is fuming from a confrontation with a dictatorial administrator who thinks they know best... (1/2)

Comment: ...and with whom the surgeon disagrees! You're invoking the image of childishness and unprofessionalism amongst surgeons who might be shaken and take umbrage to such an administrator, but in fact consultation and respect, and resolving differences of opinion by examination of its content and merit, tends to be the hallmark of professional practice, whilst dictating is more typical of stroppy children. (2/2)

Answer (score 4):

The Workplace issue here is that nothing critical should have been scheduled for 4:30 PM on a Friday unless waiting for Monday would be a disaster.

Nothing should ever be allowed to run up to a hard deadline; you should be planning to close things out with buffer time, and be planning to defer late changes to the next release -- unless they are absolutely critical AND discovered late AND you absolutely can't slip the deadline (megabucks at stake), in which case you tell your staff exactly that and they will grumble but accept it.

If the problem is that you didn't realize you needed to plan for testing, or didn't realize the team was running late, or something of that sort ... that's something you need to work on fixing as director. The fact that you were scrambling is a symptom; address the disease.

Answer (score 3):

I've been taught some important rules along my life, and two of them could apply here : 1. never ship on friday 2. measure twice as you can only saw once.

The latter means that I never ever did something wrong when testing first. I invested some little time, but never wasted it. But made big mistakes sometimes when I wanted to do anything without proper testing. They know that, even if they just want to go home or wait for monday morning to do this duty.

The former, in my opinion, would have needed some communication, if you really had to release it before the week-end. You can't expect people to welcome your decision when they're 30 minutes shy of a trip back home (or of any personal scheduled stuff).

When I need to ask this extra step to people, I first show empathy, because I really feel it. You know you're asking for something almost nobody will enjoy, no matter how professional and/or paid they are. So, be nice. It's just a small step for you, but a more important one for them.

Let them understand that you know what they feel and that you're asking for a last drop of courage. Motivate them so that this last step is done quickly and safely, then thank them for the good job.

People will stick to your ideas if they see that it has to be done, and if it can be done as a (last) team effort. Not if they're forced to do it. I'm not sure that your vote was the best thing to do then. You also opened the door to unnecessary and bitter comments afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most likely cause of the conflict is a perceived contradiction between:

1. justifying the testing process as an act of responsibility and caution; and
2. choosing to suddenly embark on the process at 4.30pm on a Friday afternoon, which is irresponsible to the extent that people are already tired, haven't had time to plan the work, and will be in a poor position to correct any mistakes they make in the process.

Insofar as the circumstances may have been an emergency, there may also be conflict about whether it is as unusual as a building fire and deserves exceptional attention, or whether it happens frequently enough or is minor enough that it could have been left until Monday morning (or should be covered by a dedicated person who is paid to be happy to routinely work later, or to be on-call).

The test of whether it is a true emergency is whether, had it happened at 1am instead of 4.30pm, would you be ringing telephones and knocking on doors to get all hands in attendance, or would you deal with it later in normal working hours?

So the OP casts the question as whether his choice to test was being too conservative or not. The real issue may be whether he'd already been too cavalier by choosing to do that work at all, rather than schedule it at a more appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

TBH I think this is more appropriate on say the DBA SE or similar - but here's my thoughts:

If a SQL operation is making a change (Upsert or delete) on multiple records or in Bulk - then it should be tested.

Now, sometimes there's a little lee-way, for example if I was doing a:

```
update Table

set colA = "Foo"

where colA = "Bar"
```

Yes, it's an update operation, but since the rollback is as simple as running it in reverse (assuming there are no other values in Col A that equal Bar, then for something like that, I might say 'It's low risk enough that we can forgo testing'.

That said, since it took an Hour of testing, I'm presuming that it wasn't such a simple change as the above.

I often have a similar healthy tension with my Boss, I'm a little more gung-ho, he's a little more cautious and together what we do works.

In terms of your specific situation, given that it took an hour to test, I don't think you were being over cautious, especially on No-Change Friday.

But let me outline some factors and ideas:

1: What was the Dollar Value lost to your client for the extra hour of downtime?
2: What would be the Dollar Value lost to your client if you had to do a full Database restore *and then have to fix the problem again, over the weekend, paying OT*?
3: How quickly could you roll back the change if something unintended happened? If the roll-back was a 5 minute process, then an hour of testing seems overkill, whereas if roll-back was a 6 hour task then...
4: If the Script fails (either to fix the underlying problem or creates additional issues) - what would be the time required to fix those additional issues?

It's not an easy tightrope to walk, but as a Manager - the above are what should guide your decision. Sometimes the cost to test is greater than the cost to rollback, in which case leniency and expediency is fine. In most cases though, the cost roll back is greater than the cost to test, hence we test.

As the old Adage says - Measure twice, Cut once.

Comment: Note that even your incredibly trivial example is fraught with danger. What if other systems act on this change, and potentially cache values, etc.